# Does javax.email support adding email signatures in the body?

Tags: java

I am using 'javax mail' to send emails, and I want to send emails with a signature in the body, but 'javax mail' doesn’t seem to support setting signatures, what should I do?

Comment: Do you mean a signature like your name and email or like a PGP type of signature?

Comment: I mean the former. such as,  at the end of email body，attach some personal information

Comment: Assuming you mean to not have the signature as an attachment, as the answer below indicates this is just appending to the body of the message.  If you're sending plain text and HTML you'll need to append to both in each of the `MimeBodyPart`s that you set for the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Signatures" don't exist structurally. They're just text at the end of the body. You can prepare whatever content you like to go in the body before sending the message.